# Is there LaTeX3's analog of \providecommand?

Tags: expl3, latex3

Suppose that one has two definitions

```
\seq_new:N \l_input_seq % declare a list (seq) variable
```

shared by 2 macros `\NewDocumentCommand`. Is there a way to check if `\l_input_seq` is already defined? Something like `\seq_provide:N`? So far I found only `\cs_if_exist:NTF` and

```
\cs_if_exist:NTF \l_input_seq { } { \seq_new:N \l_input_seq }
```

makes exactly what i need.

> **UPDATE**: In my particular case I could just use twice `\seq_new:N` to define two
>   different variables, say `\l_input_seq_one` and `\l_input_seq_two`. I
>   was just curious when posting this question ;) To say trust, I don't like to introduce plenty of temporal variables when I need only one at once.

Comment: On the update, if you look at LaTeX2e there is a lot of effort to keep down the number of scratch macros/registers as they used to be very limited. However, to do that 'safely' is tricky: it's easy to mess up. Thus the LaTeX3 approach is different: we've preferred having more macros with 'known' use patterns. Certainly for two document commands I'd expect the scratch space to be declared _outside_ of the commands, so you can happily use a single sequence if you know a clash is not possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really at the code level, although see below: we do have `\ProvideDocumentCommand`.

Broadly, you should almost always know when a new variable is needed: the general LaTeX3 approach is to define these 'early on' in a module/package. As such, if two commands use the same variable I'd expect

```
\seq_new:N \l_mypkg_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mypkg_cmd_one:n #1
  {
     ...
     \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mypkg_seq { foo }
     ...
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mypkg_cmd_two:n #1
  {
     ...
     \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mypkg_seq { bar }
     ...
  }
...
\NewDocumentCommand { \mypkgone } { m } { \mypkg_cmd_one:n {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mypkgtwo } { m } { \mypkg_cmd_two:n {#1} }
```

Very occasionally there are places where you can't be sure if a variable's been defined, usually ones created 'on the fly' from user input. For those, we provide functions of the form `\<var>_clear_new:N`, which can be used to ensure that the variable exists and is in the 'initial' state

```
\seq_clear_new:N \l_mypkg_seq
```

In a real case I'd expect these almost always to be used in the `c` form: almost always what is wanted for 'on the fly' input:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mypkg_command:n #1
  {
    \seq_clear_new:c { l_mypkg_user_data_ #1 _ seq }
    \seq_put_right:c { l_mypkg_user_data_ #1 _ seq } { First }
  }
```

Comment: So, answer is *No*: there is neither `\seq_provide:N` nor `\seq_clear_new:N`. This might be resonable since `\cs_if_exist:NTF` solves the problem of overriding temporal cs whereas introducing lot of `\..._clear_new:...` would mess existing system of LaTeX3 control sequencies.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov There definitely _is_ `\seq_clear_new:N` in the latest release of `expl3`: it's been there for some time.